# Firebase functions don't detect new functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hi I'm writing a Cloud Function for Firebase. Everything worked great but now I'm trying to deploy a new function `createRequestDoc`

The code of the function is like this:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { admin } from "../config/firebase";

const createRequestRealTimeDoc = functions
  .region("europe-west3")
  .firestore.document("/bank_requests/{documentId}")
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    console.info("here");
    const db = admin.database();
    const ref = db.ref("server/fireblog");

    // grap the content of the new request
    const request = snap.data();
    const requestRef = ref.child("requests");
    const newRequestRef = requestRef.push();
    return newRequestRef.set({ ...request });
  });

export default createRequestRealTimeDoc
```

But when I'm trying to export the function nothing happend the previous functions are deployed but not that one and I get no error message

Here are my *index.ts* with all my export

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import createOperation from "./createOperation/createOperation";
import handleRequestUpdate from "./handleRequestUpdate/handleRequestUpdate";
import createRequestRealTimeDoc
  from "./createRequestRealTimeDoc/createRequestRealTimeDoc";
import app from "./api/server";

exports.createOperation = createOperation;
exports.handleRequestUpdate = handleRequestUpdate;
exports.createRequestDoc = createRequestRealTimeDoc;
exports.app = functions.region("europe-west3").https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: What does your deployment script/command look like? Also - is your TypeScript being compiled to .js successfully before you attempt to deploy?

Comment: I fix the problem I just delete the old lib folder and now it works perfectly

Comment: @Eexy Did you just erase your `/lib` folder or did you follow other steps to get it working?
Would you mind posting your solution as a formal answer? This is to help other users that might have a problem similar to yours.

Comment: I just try to delete the old foler and it worked but I don't know why

Answer (score 2):

I fix this problem by deleting the old lib foler when ts compile and now it works perfectly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me too. Firebase was for some reason not detecting a new cron function, while previous 20 or so functions of various types worked fine. Deleting lib folder and re-deploying fixed whatever caused the issue.
 
"node": "18"
"firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
"firebase-functions": "^4.2.1",
"typescript": "^5.0.2"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Typescript and you also have a client app in the same repo, you might made the same mistake as I did:

If you accidentally import something from the frontend client folder, the the Typescript will compile the new files differently, to **include the client folder in the function lib folder.**

So to fix that you'll need to remove the import from client folder.